# With IBM ODM does the BOM implement the getters/setters from the XOM?

Tags: ibm-odm

If in your Java XOM you implement getters and setters, do the Navigation methods in the BOM execute the getters?

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, the getter and setter, if they exist, are used in preference of directly using the field, if the getter and setter are public.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, getters and setters can be used as any other methods in the rule. But, you can use the XOM even without getters and setters. And my suggestion is to go without getters and setters. Else if you need you can go..!!

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

The tricky part is that Java getters and setters typically show up in the BOM as attributes, not methods. ODM automatically maps them like that by default. And then the navigation phrase will be on the attribute. 
You can override that behavior overall by setting an option or one at a time by deleting the BOM attribute from the BOM class and definingthe getter (and setter) BOM method in its place (with B2X that references the Java method).